# KnockoutJS - How to data-bind an observable that is created inside options extend

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am extending an observable called "obsRandom" inside "extend" which looks like this:

```
var options = {
       extend: {
          "{root}": function (self) {
             self.obsRandom = ko.observable(true)
........
```

I have read about this article http://coderenaissance.github.io/knockout.viewmodel/ that explains the viewmodel plugin, but I still cannot think of a way to data-bind the created observable.

How can we do data-bind our html element

> input type="radio" data-bind="checked: ???"

to this new  extended observable?

I have tried data-bind="checked: $root.options.extend.obsRandom" but doesn't work.

Comment: From the docs, it looks like `obsRandom` should be at the top level of your viewmodel, so your binding would just be `"checked: obsRandom"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used the `ko.viewmodel` library before, and I'm not seeing enough code to give you an exact answer, but it shouldn't be hard to figure out using your browser's debugger:

1. Remove the `data-bind` property from the `<input>` element you want to create.
2. Add a temporary `id` attribute to the element: `<input id="temp-debug">`
3. Open your console and type:

   ```
   var debugCtx = ko.contextFor(document.getElementById("temp-debug"));
   ```
4. Explore the element's binding context. The most important parts:

   - `$root` will show you what your root viewmodel looks like
   - `$data` will show you what the element's viewmodel looks like
   - `$parents` is an array that stores each level between `$root` and `$data`

Using the console you can try out different queries and find out the right data-bind. For example: you can check what the path you tried returns by querying: `debugCtx.$root.options.extend.obsRandom`